# Back button to another storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, navigation, storyboard

I am creating an iOS app which consists of 2 storyboards.

This is the second one:

[image: Storyboard]

I am targeting iOS 7 so I cant use storyboard references. Switch between storyboards is handled programmatically

Using this code:

```
 let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Warnings", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WarningsInitialView") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I can get to the second storyboard using this. However as you can see second storyboard consists of Tab Controller and I want (on both tabs) back button which will point to the main (previous) storyboard. How should I achieve this?

I have tried using this code:

```
AvalanchesBackButton.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem (title: "< Spät", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backButtonClicked")
```

I will be able to achieve what I want by using different view controllers for both views and hardcoding it. But is there a way to do it more cleanly? Like implement a back button on container Tab Controller which will point to previous storyboard?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your previous ViewController embedded into a Navigation controller? because "pushing" the view controller automatically adds the back button.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

Comment: yes it is in navigation controller. So you suggest that I switch to view in another storyboard by not using my code but by using the code you posted?

Comment: thanks your answer is working. I replaced presentviewcontroller line with your line and it works.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I would upvote it by 10 if I could :)