# No response when attempting to switch to different view controller in different storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I've got a button on storyboard Alpha that leads to storyboard Beta using the following code:

```
@IBAction func showBeta(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Beta", bundle: nil)
    let bvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BetaViewController") as! BetaViewController

    self.present(bvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This works without any problems.

However, I ran into the issue of not having a back button in Beta because self.present makes the new view appear modally.

I then read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046445/back-button-to-another-storyboard) where the poster had the same problem as me. The answer suggested this code:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

So I changed my code to:

```
@IBAction func showBeta(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Beta", bundle: nil)
    let bvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BetaViewController") as! BetaViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bvc, animated: true)
}
```

However, now nothing happens at all when clicking the button. No errors, nothing. What's going on here?

Comment: Is your first view controller in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `AlphaViewController` isn't embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Try this piece of code:

```
@IBAction func showBeta(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Beta", bundle: nil)
    let bvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BetaViewController") as! BetaViewController

    show(bvc, sender: self)
}
```

This will cause your `BetaViewController` appear modally if your `AlphaViewController` isn't embedded in navigation controller and you won't get the back button. But if your `AlphaViewController` is embedded in navigation controller then your `BetaViewController` will be shown as left-to-right transition and you will get your desired back button.

### To add navigation controller:

If you added your `AlphaViewController` from interface builder, follow this to embed it in a navigation controller: `Select`**AlphaViewController** `-> Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller`

Or, if you added your controller programmatically, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810501/3687801).